# Json parsing in go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am trying to parse json in [this](https://api.github.com/events) url. My code is as below, but the output is not as expected. I want to extract id, url inside payload only for pushevent. How do i do that . Thanks

```
type events struct {
    id string `json:"id"`
}

func pullUrlFromGit(urlHolder chan string){

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, _ := client.Get("https://api.github.com/events")
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body,_ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    var gtevents []events
    json.Unmarshal(body,&gtevents)

    log.Printf("%+v",gtevents)
}
```

The output i am getting is as below.

```
[{id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:} {id:}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `id` field uppercase

```
type events struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
}
```

Go json library uses reflection to access fields of structures. Reflection allows only exported fields to be modified. Therefore you need to make that field exported by making the first letter uppercase.

See [Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_10.)

Comment: thanks..you are right

Comment: Just a follow up question. 
I got the output as below  when I added Type and Paylod

{Id:4787366250 Type:IssueCommentEvent Payload:{Size:0}} {Id:4787366249 Type:PushEvent Payload:{Size:1}} 

Is there way to filter Type in the Struct itself ? What I meant was, can I do the below

type events struct {
 Id string `json:"id"`
 Type string `json:"type":"PushEvent"`
 Payload eventPayload `json:"payload"`
}
Checking whether type is PushEvent